# Place emitter type particles on the surface evenly

Tags: mesh, objects, particles

I'm trying to recreate this effect:

[image]

I've managed to deform a cylinder to get the wave effect like so:

[image]

However, I'm not able to evenly add the particle objects since my emitter does not have even faces. A noob-friendly guide to adding the particles on the surface evenly would be extremely apprectiated! Thanks!

Comment: You could create one more mesh and shrinkwrap it atop of this one, Remesh modifier could be used there to ensure more even topology. Still that looks more like parametric modelling, e.g. Sverchok addon

Answer (score 1):

### Final:

[image: Final]

You can make it **with Ocean Modifier** (it will keep mesh evenly distributed) and **Particles System**.

### Ocean Modifier:

Add **Ocean Modifier** to any mesh (could be **Plane**). And literally just play with settings until you will be satisfied. I've marked my settings for this example.

Remember to check how much **Verts** your mesh contain as this will be important in **Particles** setup.

Do this in **Wireframe** view to see density of the mesh.

[image: ocean]

### Particles:

Add **Particle System** to your mesh.

Set **Start/End** to **0** and **Particle Number** to match mesh **Verts** count. Sometimes Blender will leave a gap (I don't know why) you can fix this by adding one more **Particle**. In this example it's ok, but with earlier try I've needed to increase it by 1.

Check **Use Modifier Stack**, this will allow to use mesh generated by **Ocean Modifier**.

Add to the scene mesh you want to use as a render object. In this example it is simple **IcoSphere**. Select it under **Render** tab > **Dupli Object**.

[image: particles]

### Final thoughts:

You can manipulate **Ocean Modifier** after adding **Particle System**. Just remember that changing **Resolution** or **Repeat X/Y** will change **Verts** count and then you will need to change **Particles Number** accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the shape you already have, just change the emitter type to **grid**, increase **resolution** value and make sure that none of the random values is switched on.
[image]

Here is a mesh a made

[image]

A the result

[image]

Remember to turn off **gravity** and **normal** values so the particles will stay in place
[image]